# Nativescript / TypeScript error - error TS5053: Option 'sourceMap' cannot be specified with option 'inlineSourceMap'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "watch": true
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "platforms"
],
"compileOnSave": true
}
```

Above is my tsconfig.json .  I'm getting an error that I'm not understanding why i'm getting.  any thoughts?

### Here's the errors in debug console in vscode i'm getting

```
[NativeScriptCli] execute: tns --version
[NSDebugAdapter] Using tns CLI v2.5.0 on path 'tns'
[NSDebugAdapter] Running tns command...
[NativeScriptCli] execute: tns debug ios --no-client --watch 
[NSDebugAdapter] Watching the tns CLI output to receive a connection token
Executing before-prepare hook from /Users/USERNAME/Projects/Project-tns/hooks/before-prepare/nativescript-dev-sass.js
Executing before-prepare hook from /Users/USERNAME/Projects/Project-tns/hooks/before-prepare/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Found peer TypeScript 2.2.0
error TS5053: Option 'sourceMap' cannot be specified with option 'inlineSourceMap'.
7:34:42 AM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

Comment: In that file - remove the sourceMap option - ts won't generate the .map files any more. Not sure where the inlineSourceMap is specified.

Comment: thank you so much that fixed it :-)

Comment: @dashman It didnt work out for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433144/error-ts5053-option-sourcemap-cannot-be-specified-with-option-inlinesourcema

Answer (score 8):

dashman's answer of removing the source map option from tsconfig.json was what fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @dashmam, the `inlineSourceMap` compiler option is lurking around somewhere.

For me, I had it specified in my webpack config. You must **either** remove/switch `inlineSourceMap: true` or `sourceMap: true`.

Also worth investigating - if your `tsconfig.json` extends another `tsconfig.json`, you may want to look there for a similar conflict

Answer (score 0):

In my case it didn't work to remove the `sourceMap: true`, in fact it is not necessary to remove it. The problem was my company's network restrictions. I connected to my mobile data and the error disappeared.